# SVG viewer alternative for flash rendering in IE

Tags: java, javascript

Hi i have a problem with svg viewer in Internet Explorer, because i use flash, maybe you can suggest me another solution for this browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Plugin for Internet Explorer is very seamless.  We use it in several projects and have been able to display a simple error message to the user indicating that they need to install the plugin.